# How to handle a click which is not handled by Listeners?

Tags: android, onclick, listener, onclicklistener

I have an application with several Buttons so far. 
How can you set up an `onClick()` Event that fires when something else than the buttons which are currently `clickable` are clicked?
In my case: There is a tutorial, and when you click something except the possible buttons that can be clicked, I want to pop up a message saying ("This is not `clickable` right now, please click X").

Answer (score 0):

Every `View` can receive an `onClick` event which can be catched with a Listener.

If what you want to do is listen for all click events and have specific actions performed when the buttons are clicked, and for anything else that gets click show a message, you can set the Activity as an `OnClickListener` and then check which is the view that was clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      View v = findViewById(R.id.top_most_view);
      v.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
       if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
         // do something for the button
       }else if(v.getId == R.id.button2){
         // other button 
       }else{
         // Show the non clickable message
       }
   }

}
```

R.id.top_most_view is the id of the top most view of your layout. For example a LinearLayout that contains all the other views.

In the example I put only two buttons but you can add as many as you want. Also you can use a switch instead of cascading ifs.

The code may have some typo, I didn't test it. But you should get the general idea of how to implement the solution.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this